# When I use pycurl to execute a curl command, I get error 3 "illegal characters found in URL" but when pasting said URL in Chome, it can be resolved

Tags: python-3.x, facebook, curl, pycurl

Good day. I'm writing a python program that requests some posts from my Facebook page. To do so, Facebook offers a tool that they call "Graph API Explorer". Using something similar to a GET request, I can get anything that I want (granted that I have access and a valid token). I've come up with my own solution for the Graph API Explorer and that is generating my URLs. After generating a URL, I use pycurl to get a JSON object from Facebook that contains all of my data.

When I use pycurl, I get the following error:
`pycurl.error: (3, 'Illegal characters found in URL')`

but when printing said URL and pasting it to a browser, I got a valid response.

URL: `https://graph.facebook.com/v7.0/me?fields=posts%7Bmessage%2Cfrom%7D&access_token=<and my access token which is valid>`

my code looks like this:

```
def get_posts_curl(nodes=['posts'], fields=[['message', 'from']], token_file='Facebook/token.txt'):
    curl = pycurl.Curl()
    response = BytesIO()
    token = get_token_from_file(token_file)

    # constructing request.
    url = parse_facebook_url_request(nodes, fields, token)
    url = convert_to_curl(url)

    print("---URL---: " + url)

    # curl session and settings.
    curl.setopt(curl.CAINFO, certifi.where())
    curl.setopt(curl.URL, url)
    curl.setopt(curl.WRITEDATA, response)
    curl.perform()
    curl.close()
    return response.getvalue().decode('utf-8')
```

The error pops up at `curl.perform()`

Some info that might be relevant:
All was working great a while ago. After transferring my program from my workstation (that is running Windows 10) to my server (Ubuntu 18.04 Server) still, all was working fine and I placed that project to the side. Only now that error pops up and I haven't touched the project in a while.

Comment: You should be escaping the tokens.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the token is causing the issue. I've tried about 100 tokens and some cause the problem and some don't. Also, a fix that solved it all was using urllib3.unquote

```
from urllib.parse import unquote

...
url = unquote(url)
```